# Is the Honeycomb Status bar (at the bottom) the same height across devices?

Tags: android, screen, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm trying to figure out if the Status bar (the one that has the Home and Back buttons) is consistant across devices, in terms of how many vertical pixels it occupies, and if so what that number is, and if not what do I do to get the height dynamically, so that I can act accordingly with the remaining screen real estate.

I see a couple of other questions that sort of skirt this topic, but none that actually give a definitive answer.

TIA

Comment: Can't you just ask the current `Window` what its dimensions are, rather than presumably taking the full screen resolution and subtracting the status bar height?

Comment: @Christopher, I suppose so. I was assuming there'd be a less hack(y) approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to figure out if the Status bar (the one that has the Home and Back buttons) is consistant across devices

It is not even consistent on the same device.

One example: if you plug a WXGA device into a television via HDMI and hold it in landscape, the system bar will grow a bit, so that the space outside the system bar will be exactly 720p (1280x720, with an 80px high system bar).

> if so what that number is

It is a non-negative integer. Everything else is undocumented and, therefore, subject to change.

> what do I do to get the height dynamically

You don't. You do not care about the system bar. You care about the space you can draw in and how big that is. Whether there is zero, one, two, or twenty system bars does not matter.

> I was assuming there'd be a less hack(y) approach.

What Christopher suggested *is* the "less hack(y) approach". What you were trying to do is significantly more hacky, as it makes assumptions about what might be intruding upon your drawing space.

Answer (score 0):

Since it uses Density Independent Pixels, yes. If you whipped out a ruler and measured it, it'd be the same height on every device.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel Well, if you can count the pixels and figure out the scale factor for your device then I guess that'd be your answer. But in all seriousness... I have no idea.

Comment: Assuming HTC, Samsung, Sony and everyone else with their skinned version of Android create their status bar with the same `dp` height to begin with..

Comment: @Christopher good point. My statement is only true for stock android I guess.